# Azure DevOps Releases - How to carry out a Test Stage at a specific virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, integration-testing

After `Azure => Pipelines`, I end up with two published artifacts: one containing a .NET Core Console Application (`myDrop`), another containing the corresponding Testing library (written with xUnit) (`myTestDrop`). Then I move on to `Azure => Releases` to create a new Release Pipeline as below:

[image]

I have a Windows Virtual Machine (VM), which is already installed with all necessary libraries, e.g. .NET Core; and I would like to carry out the Integration Testing (the **2nd Stage** above) in that machine. Specifically,

1. Copy both `myDrop` and `myTestDrop` to that VM.
2. Set some Environment Variable: the path to, let's say, `MyConsole.exe` in `myDrop`.
3. Then run the Integration Test: `dotnet vstest "MyConsole.Tests.dll" --logger:trx --ResultsDirectory:"c:/Somewhere" /TestCaseFilter:"Category=IntegrationTest"`
4. If the test is successful, the returned code from `dotnet.exe` is `0` (otherwise, `1`).
5. The 3rd Stage only runs in case the 2nd Stage is successful.
6. There should be a way to read `*.trx` generated from the Integration Test above, especially in case there are some test failures.

My experience with Azure DevOps is limited. I have searched around but most Azure Release examples involve Web Application (IIS, SQL...), not a normal Console Application with Test on a specific VM. Feel free to suggest other alternatives or best practices, given the scenario above.

Any advice, suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to carry out a Test Stage at a specific virtual machine?

You can install and use a self-hosted agent in that machine. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to install Self-hosted Windows agents. You need to add an agent job to the release pipeline first. Then, choose the agent pool with self-hosted agent installed. [image]

> Copy both myDrop and myTestDrop to that VM.

Since your agent is installed on the VM, it will automatically download artifacts to its local folder.

> The 3rd Stage only runs in case the 2nd Stage is successful.

You can select “After Stage” trigger in  pre-deployment conditions.  For example, if the test stage in your screenshot fails, the deployment stage will not deploy.
[image]

> There should be a way to read *.trx generated from the Integration
> Test above, especially in case there are some test failures.

You can check the test results in the Tests tab of the release result page. You can also download the *.trx file on this page.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I still have one small issue. In "Publish Test Results" task, "Search folder" section, how can I make use of the environment variable `ABC` set in the former task, via `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ABC]Something here"`?

Comment: You can use $(ABC) in your Search folder section. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts).

Comment: To be clear, the environment variable `ABC` is set in a Command Line Script task. In the latter Task (Publish Test Result), in section "Search Folder", I tried the following options, but none of them worked. (`$($env:ABC)`, `$env:ABC`, `$(ABC)`, `%ABC%`, `$ABC`, `$[ABC]`, `$[variables.ABC]`).